# consulta en Linq to entities leftjoin con una campo extra

Tags: vb.net, linq

Buenas, necesito obtener los objetos que hay en una colección que si existen en otra, un campo diga "existe", y si no existen diga "no existe"

El objeto de `ProgramasLivianos` tiene un campo que se llama `TienePrograma`. Me interesaría que se pueda cargar en ese campo si tiene o no. Este objeto "programasLivianos" lo tengo en una lista llamada "ListaResultado"

Ejemplo:

```
ListaProgramas=  {nombre, codSiu, stream, .....} -> muchos campos extras

ListaProgramasAlumno = {nombrePrograma, AñoAprobado, plan} -> datos del legajo

ListaResultado = {nombrePrograma, TienePrograma} -> esto deberia salir de la consulta que busco, donde el campo TienePrograma deberia ser devuelto de la consulta
```

Ocurre que a veces el alumno tiene programas que no estan cargados todavia, entonces quisiera hacer una consulta que me devuelva `nombreDelPrograma` (extraido del legajo) y si ese programa no existe en la `listaProgramas` que el campo `TienePrograma` se cargue con "NO"

Código que he intentado:

```
Dim r As List(Of programas_ft_V)
r = db.ProgramaFileTable_VSet.Where(Function(x) x.unc_path.Contains("\programas_ft\programasSubidosWeb\") AndAlso
                                                                                        x.is_archive).ToList
Dim listaDT As New List(Of ProgramasLivianos) '= dataTable.AsEnumerable.ToList()
listaDT = ProgramasLivianos.CrearLista(dataTable)
Dim resultadoI = From l In r, p In listaDT
                    Where l.name.Contains(p.codSiu)
                    Select New ProgramasLivianos  With {  p.codSiu, p.nombre, p.nombre_Reducido, p.plan, p.tieneTaller, p.tienePrograma = "NoTienePrograma"}
```

Comment: ese codigo tiene un error. Pero es para que se vea la idea.

Comment: Dices que el código tiene un error, podrías especificar cual?  También ayudaría que pusieras un [MCVE] con la definición de `ProgramasLivianos`, que datos estan en las listas y que esperas obtener

Comment: corregido... a ver si ahora me explico. Elimine ese codigo porque podia traer confusion

Comment: Creo que ahora está mas claro efectivamente. A ver si podemos ayudarte:)

Comment: He añadido el código que intentaste porque puede ayudar a entender mejor todavía lo que necesitas. Además en este sitio se valora mucho que haya un esfuerzo previo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que comentas necesitas realizar un left join. Aqui tienes una referencia de como se puede realizar una [left join mediante linq](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#leftouterjoin)

Te pongo un ejemplo base de como podría ser en tu caso (modifica los campos que necesites):

```
 var resultadoI  = from l In ListaProgramas
    join p in ListaProgramasAlumno on p.nombrePrograma.Contains(l.codSiu) into lp
    from p in lp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { nombrePrograma = p.nombrePrograma, TienePrograma = p == null ? "(NO)" : p.nombrePrograma};
```

Comment: interesante.. voy a probarlo.. gracias